# Send email to multiple people based on common cell value using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I would like to add multiple recipients and attachments to one email message dictated by the value in a column.

I need to have people update their resumes, which will be attached, but I would like to group the emails by manager. The # of people under each manager ranges from 1-14.

The columns I have are:
B: Mgr Email address
C: Mgr last name
D: Employee email
E: Emp first name
F: Emp last name
G: Status of resume

I created a macro that will loop through and create an email with proper attachment for each entry.

I'd like to switch this to groups of employees by the value in column C or B. I have an inkling this will include arrays. I am a VBA novice.

What I have so far (with specific paths/emails renamed for privacy):

```
Sub Test2()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim sSourcePath As String
Dim flpath As String
flpath = "C:\Resumes\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    'XYZ email address was hardcoded for testing purposes, but should also loop
    If cell.Value = "XYZ@gmail.com" And _
       Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value = "4. Need Update" _
       Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        sSourcePath = Dir(flpath & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value & " *.docx")

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value & ", " & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value
            'cced address is static
            .CC = "ZZZ@gmail.com" 
            .Subject = "Resume needed"
            .body = "Howdy!" _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Body text"

            .attachments.Add flpath & sSourcePath
            .Display  'Or use Display

        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If

Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to send one e-mail to the manager of everyone who needs to update his résumé? You want to send one e-mail and cc: everyone who has the same manager, attaching all résumés? I'm not sure what you mean by "I'd like to switch this to groups of employees by the value in column C or B."  Also, how will you choose which column to use? Like, if last name is blank, use e-mail? But that might create multiple groups for the same manager. etc. Seems like some detail is missing.

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the sheet by column B or C?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing correctly at what you want, here's a way that uses a collection of e-mails by manager. They are created as you go, and then when you're finished, you can do whatever you want to the messages in the collection.

```
Dim allMessages as Collection
Dim currMessage as Object
Set allMessages = New Collection

For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value = "4. Need Update"
        ' Find the e-mail for the present manager
        For Each currMessage in allMessages
            If currMessage.CC = cell.Value Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next currMessage

        ' Create it, if it wasn't found
        If currMessage Is Nothing Then
            Set currMessage = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            allMessages.Add currMessage
            With currMessage
                .CC = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Résumé Needed"
                .Body = "Howdy!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Body text."
            End With
        End If

        ' Add the Message Recipient and Attachment
        sSourcePath = Dir(flpath & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value & " *.docx")
        With currMessage
            .To = .To & Iif(Len(.To) > 0,";","") & _
                  cell.Value & ", " & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value
            .Attachments.Add flpath & sSourcePath
        End With

        Set currMessage = Nothing

    End If
Next cell

' Now do something with the messages.
For Each currMessage In allMessages
    currMessage.Display
End If

Set currMessage = Nothing
Set allMessages = Nothing
```

**Caveat:** Given that I don't have your data and don't use Outlook presently, I have not tested the above code snippet. The snippet primarily replaces your `For...Next`Loop, with an additional loop and clean up at the end, some declarations at the beginning. Let me know if it gives you problems, and I'll try to fix this answer based on what you tell me.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a test. To answer your previous questions, I can certainly sort the sheet. Also, I am hoping to send one e-mail and cc: everyone who has the same manager, attaching all résumés. I just meant Col C or B, doesn't matter which to choose. C is likely better anyways. Thanks again, I'll see how this works!

Comment: If you sort the sheet, you don't need the collection. You can sort by the column you want, and walk down through the list building your message. When the manager name changes, send the one you've built and start a new one. The code currently provided doesn't require the sheet to be sorted.

Comment: The code is having compiling errors - it doesn't understand where the bottom End If in the first chunk is coming from:
If Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value = "4. Need Update"
        ' Find the e-mail for the present manager
        For Each currMessage in allMessages
            If currMessage.CC = cell.Value Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

It also doesn't understand the Next cell or End If right above the Next cell. Any insight?

Comment: I put an End If at the end of the For loop instead of a Next. Sorry. I'll fix it.

Comment: It should be all set now.